# mm-qcamera-daemon causing massive battery drain

Tags: battery-life, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

Recently, `mm-qcamera-daemon` has been causing massive battery drain on my Nexus 5, and making it become rather warm. At the same time, the camera appears to be locked, meaning opening the default camera app (or any camera app) causes the alert `Camera is currently in use` to appear.

Numerous forums around the web site apps such as `Snapchat` and a Yahoo video app as the issues, but I've never installed these apps before.

Restarting the phone does seem to fix the issue, but after awhile (more than 12h) later, the battery starts draining again.

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE**: Like the top answer says, this problem should have been fixed by the 4.4.4 Kitkat update that rolled out.

Comment: Something is definitely accessing the camera. Do you have any security software like Cerberus installed that takes pictures when you get your pin/pw wrong? It could be accessing the camera and failing to release it when done. Or it could be another app with camera permissions. If you are rooted, you could probably see in the log files what is accessing the camera, although know that this can be tedious.

Comment: @abqnm its nothing to do with that, see the answer below given by piotrpo, its a firmware problem on Nexus 5.

Comment: @t0mm13b thanks. Hadn't seen that issue. Also from the looks of it, it has only started in the last few days. This would lead me to believe that it may have something to do with a recent Play Services update.

Comment: I have 4.4.4 and problem appeared after some app update. Are there tool to monitor which app is causing issue? Is it skype again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

Wait for the next Android maintenance update:

[Comment #475 on issue 60058](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60058)

> Thanks, everyone, for reporting about this problem.
>
> We believe we have fixes for the current high CPU reports on N5 due to
>   mm-qcamera-daemon, and they will be included in the next maintenance
>   update. At this point, we don't need more reports of the problem, with
>   some exceptions I'll detail below.
>
> More details:
>
> We've had scattered reports of persistent high CPU usage of
>   mm-qcamera-daemon since our last maintenance update, and based on
>   those, found a number of bugs that were then fixed.
>
> More recently, there's been a significant increase in the frequency of
>   reported problems. These may be related to a recent update to Skype,
>   which seems to access the camera regularly from its background service
>   in some way that triggers this bug (note, we don't currently believe
>   there's a bug in Skype itself). Investigating this, we've identified a
>   few additional fixes that we hope resolve this issue for good. 
>   However, since the high CPU usage is an intermittent problem, we're
>   continuing to test our fixes to verify the problems are gone.
>
> Unfortunately, I can't provide an estimate for when the maintenance
>   update will be ready, due to all the testing we need to do for this
>   and other fixes. Until then, rebooting the phone is the only way to
>   stop the high CPU usage/lack of camera function once it starts.
>
> Uninstalling Skype may substantially reduce the likelihood of this bug
>   appearing, but I realize Skype is a very important application for
>   many people.  Other camera-using applications may trigger this bug as
>   well, but that's been relatively rare. Most applications also do not
>   access the camera when not in the foreground, so they will only
>   trigger issues when actively used.
>
> I'd also like to note that instances of high CPU use of
>   mm-qcamera-daemon on other devices besides the N5 need to be reported
>   to their manufacturers - while those devices also use a Qualcomm chip
>   for their camera processing (and thus have a mm-qcamera-daemon
>   process), each has differences in their software and issues with them
>   do not necessarily mean the N5 has the same problem, and vice versa.
>
> If you are seeing high CPU use of mm-qcamera-daemon, and you have not
>   used the camera at all, or installed an application like Skype that
>   has a background service that accesses the camera (typically,
>   applications that provide video chat may do this), we would like to
>   know about it.
>
> Otherwise, for Skype and other typical camera applications, we believe
>   we have fixes identified, and you don't need to add more information
>   to this bug - remember, any note added here will send updates to
>   dozens of people.

Comment: Yes, Google has acknowledged this bug, and should be in the next KitKat update. Reference: [Cult of Android: Google Vows To Fix Android 4.4.2’s Camera Battery Drain Bug](http://www.cultofandroid.com/53672/google-vows-fix-android-4-4-2s-camera-battery-drain-bug/)

Comment: FYI - Skype has just updated to v4.7 which includes a fix for battery drain on 4.4 devices. "Workaround for the KitKat bug which caused a runaway process when the camera was synced in the background." [Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/18/skype-for-android-hits-version-4-7-brings-major-under-the-hood-redesign-that-results-in-substantial-battery-savings/)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem - after uninstall of Skype and phone's restart problem disapeared.

More information you can find here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60058

I have N5 4.4.2 - I understand that some camera apps can cause this issue - for me - Skype is camera application. At this moment the only non-system application with camera access is zxing code reader.
All I know is that this error occured while I had Skype installed, and had not occured since the uninstall of Skype. I do not know if is it coincidence, or I "solved" the problem.

Comment: Why are you assuming the OP has Skype, gave no indication of that either.

Comment: I don't know that - simply - this fixed problem on my nexus (as far as now) - I don't know what is the matter of issue so I can't say if skype was really draining or it was just coincidence.

Comment: I highly doubt its to do with Skype or any other video app, from reading the above linky (thanks for that) in your edited answer - its more prevalent issue on Nexus 5 and KitKat, which would go some way to explaining the issue, see #358 onwards, snapchat/instagram or any other, is not the source, its firmware issue with KitKat. You have Nexus 5 with Kitkat? +1 from me for that linky! :)

Comment: I do have Skype installed but I've used App Ops to revoke its camera permissions, yet this isssue is still occurring.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my Nexus 5 (stock). mm-qcamera-daemon was draining 50% according to battery stats. The issue started when I tried to take photo from Hangout app, camera could not started. I don't have Snapchat or use Skype for video call from my phone.

I went to Apps and cleared data for `Camera` app.

[**Old**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60058#c435):
By far, I now see the percentage dropping to 24%. My phone does not get hot when using other apps as it did while qcamera service was running.

**New:** 
`mm-qcamera-daemon` is not even in the battery stats list. 2 days by now. I regularly use Hangout app, which initially triggered `mm-qcamera-daemon`.

[image]

I can't say this is a fix or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.

In the Google bug thread, someone suggested a temp fix that worked for them. Install [Disable Camera device ICS/JB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.neko.freewing.DisableCameraDevice).

While not being able to take pics without enabling the camera is a pain, randomly having a dead battery on your N5 is worse.

I have installed the app and will see if it helps me any.

[image]

Comment: Update: Since I installed the disable camera app I haven't had this problem so far.