# How to list apps, which have a permission to access the camera?

Tags: applications, battery, battery-life, camera, permissions

I am experiencing the problem with the `mm-qcamera-daemon` on a Nexus 5 **with 4.4.4**, as described in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64569/mm-qcamera-daemon-causing-massive-battery-drain). I would like to know if there is a way to see which apps have a permission to access the camera, so I can decide which app is causing the problem.

Comment: See [How can I find which apps/packages reference a given permission using command line?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several apps in the Play Store that can list which applications use specific permissions.  One that I use is Permission Friendly Apps by androidsoft.org

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidsoft.app.permission

It requires no permissions itself so it's safe to use.  Once you install it, you can look through the built in views or filter down to a specific permission.  The one you  want to start with for this issue is "Take Pictures and Videos".  This will narrow down the list of installed apps to just those that can access your camera.