# How can I find which apps/packages reference a given permission using command line?

Tags: permissions, command-line

Given some permission `tld.developer.app.permission.PERMISSION` how can I use adb/root shell to find all the installed packages that define/depend on it?

The permissions are defined in the manifest files and it is possible to transfer each apk over from `/data/app`, `/system/app`, `/system/priv-app`, etc., unpackage, and check, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first section is ideally supposed to be OS (on PC) independent. The solution heavily depends upon the output of *package* service. It has been successfully tested on Android 4.2.1, 5.0.2 and 5.1.1 - all these versions are not heavily modified from stock Android.

### Dependencies

- Requires [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to be setup in PC.
- Requires *busybox* binary. If the device is rooted, install [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) app. Else, download busybox binary from [official source](https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/), rename the binary to *busybox*, set Linux compatible [executable permission](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php) on that binary for everyone and move it into device using

  ```
  adb push LOCAL_FILE /data/local/tmp/   # LOCAL_FILE is the file path where busybox binary is located in PC
  ```
- Requires *aapt* binary. If you're running a CM or its derivative ROM then ignore this requirement. Otherwise, for Android 4.x, you can consider downloading the binary from [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/downloads), rename the binary to *aapt*, set Linux compatible [executable permission](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php) on that binary for everyone and move it into device using

  ```
  adb push LOCAL_FILE /data/local/tmp/   # LOCAL_FILE is the file path where busybox binary is located in PC .
  ```

  Android 5.x users: ask Google for assistance.

Here's my little script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
# Check if the busybox binary exists under /data/local/tmp/ or /system/xbin. Set the detected binary's path into the variable busybox or exit if file doesn't exist or executable permission is not set
[[ -x /data/local/tmp/busybox ]] && busybox=/data/local/tmp/busybox || { [[ -x /system/xbin/busybox ]] && busybox=/system/xbin/busybox || { date +'busybox binary not found or executable permission is not set. Exiting' && exit; }; }

# Check if the aapt binary exists under /data/local/tmp or /system/bin or /system/xbin. Set the detected binary's path into the variable aapt or exit if file doesn't exist or executable permission is not set
[[ -x /data/local/tmp/aapt ]] && aapt=/data/local/tmp/aapt || { [[ -x /system/bin/aapt ]] && aapt=/system/bin/aapt || { [[ -x /system/xbin/aapt ]] && aapt=/system/xbin/aapt || { date +'aapt binary not found or executable permission is not set. Exiting' && exit; }; }; }

# Validate input
! [[ "$1" == +([0-9a-zA-Z._]) ]] && { $busybox printf 'Permission field should not be empty or contain anything beyond these characters: a-zA-Z0-9._' && exit; } || perm=$1;

# List package name of all the installed apps and save them in the file packages.txt under /sdcard
pm list packages | $busybox sed 's/^package://g' | $busybox sort -o /sdcard/packages.txt
$busybox printf "List of apps defining and/or depending on the permission $perm:\n\n";

# Take each line (a package name) from the file packages.txt. In the output of package service for that package name, see if the permission is granted or defined and set appropriate variable state. For different states, we're either dumping the label of the app using aapt, printing the status of define/granted permissions for package or simply moving on.
while read line; do 
    [[ `dumpsys package $line | grep -Eo "^[ ]+$perm"` ]] && granted=1 || granted=0;
    [[ `dumpsys package $line | grep -Eo "^[ ]+Permission[ ]+\[$perm\][ ]+\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\):"` ]] && defined=1 || defined=0;
    [[ $granted == 1 || $defined == 1 ]] && path=$(pm path $line | $busybox sed 's/^package://g') && label=$($aapt d badging $path 2>&1 | $busybox sed -ne '/application: label=/p' | $busybox cut -d "'" -f2);
    [[ $granted == 1 && $defined == 1 ]] && $busybox printf "$label ($line)\nDefined: Yes\nGranted: Yes\n\n";
    [[ $granted == 1 && $defined != 1 ]] && $busybox printf "$label ($line)\nDefined: No\nGranted: Yes\n\n";
    [[ $granted != 1 && $defined == 1 ]] && $busybox printf "$label ($line)\nDefined: Yes\nGranted: No\n\n";
done < /sdcard/packages.txt
```

Save the script in PC into a file named `perm_script.sh` and move it into /sdcard using

```
adb push LOCAL_FILE /sdcard/   # LOCAL_FILE is the  path where you saved that file into PC
```

Run that file

```
adb shell sh /sdcard/perm_script.sh PERMISSION   # replace PERMISSION with the android permission for which apps are to be shown
```

Demo output:

```
List of apps defining and/or depending on the permission android.permission.FLASHLIGHT:

Android System (android)
Defined: Yes
Granted: No

Automagic Premium (ch.gridvision.ppam.androidautomagic)
Defined: No
Granted: Yes

MacroDroid (com.arlosoft.macrodroid)
Defined: No
Granted: Yes

Google+ (com.google.android.apps.plus)
Defined: No
Granted: Yes
...
Bluetooth (com.mediatek.bluetooth)
Defined: No
Granted: Yes

DS Battery Saver Pro (com.rootuninstaller.batrsaverpro)
Defined: No
Granted: Yes

Webkey (com.webkey)
Defined: No
Granted: Yes
```

Do note that all those apps and their permissions among other things can also be found in the file `/data/system/packages.xml`.

---

<sub>(To get app's label using its package name, use GAThrawn's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19866/96277) - works if only the app is available in Play Store; use Izzy's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115664/96277) - works for any installed app.)</sub>

Comment: got an error running your script, did i miss something? adb shell sh /sdcard/perm_script.sh PERMISSION
/sdcard/perm_script.sh[6]: syntax error: '{' unmatched or directly running on the android 8 Script output
Finished executing script file
exit value:1 stdout:
null stderr:
/sdcard/perm_script.sh[6]: sysntax error: '{' unmatched

Comment: @Gidabytes I have just tested my script on Android 8.1 (in OnePlus 6), and it works. You might be doing something wrong in copying the script's content I suppose. You can ask a separate question for that, and reference my answer, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (Android 8):

```
cmd appops query-op RUN_IN_BACKGROUND allow | sort
```

It shows which packages have `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND` mode enabled.

Comment: This is a good and easy to use solution, but it has some shortcomings too. First, it only allows querying dangerous permissions, because appops works only for that, so [normal permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal_permissions) cannot be queried with this. Second, it requires multiple executions to ascertain which apps have a said permission allowed, default, denied, or ignored.