# Can I know who is changing Android's media volume?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, htc, volume-control

Recently my phone's media volume will be changed to a fixed value in period automatically. I guess there's a bad app running in background or by alarm doing this, but I have no idea which one is the convict.

Is there a way to let me know who is changing system media volume? My device is an *HTC Butterfly 3* running Android 5.0.2 official ROM – and power saving is not turned on (in case it matters). Thanks!

Comment: Need to know what device you are using. Also, do you have the "Power Saving" feature turned on, on your device. (Cannot tell you how to check as you did not list what device you are using.) If you know how to turn the "Power Saving" feature on/off on your device, try turning it OFF, and see if your volumes auto-set themselves again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my COS12 (Android 5.0.2), I noticed that whenever the volume was changed an intent was broadcasted with action `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` and that was all I was able to see using *dumpsys* or [logcat](/questions/tagged/logcat). The *extras* in that intent did not contain anything useful to trace the app.

Anyhow. Following is what I can recommend as an approach and as of now:

Install [aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat)<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>, uncheck *Ignore system apps* from its settings and under *List apps by permission* browse the  section *Audio Settings*. This app missed some system apps which my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123100/96277) took care of<sup><sup>2</sup></sup>.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

I suggest you check [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name) and find out the package name of all the apps listed by aSpotCat. After that, uninstall all the user installed apps involved. Since removal may not be a preferable option for you, you can consider hiding/blocking them. Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and do:

```
adb shell pm block PACKAGE # for KitKat
adb shell pm hide PACKAGE  # for Lollipop
```

*PACKAGE* should be replaced by package name of the app. In short, the effect observed from that command is akin to removing an app from your OS with major difference that the app's data and UID *would remain preserved*.

To reinstate the app, replace *hide* by *unhide* and *block* by *unblock* in aforesaid commands.

You would have to wait and observe if the volume is getting changed. If yes, hide/block/remove those user installed apps singularly or in bulk and then go into observation mode again. If all the user installed apps are removed yet the change in media volume can be observed then a system app is involved in the process. If you've a custom [recovery](/questions/tagged/recovery) installed or you're ready to [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) the device, **only then** you should consider hiding/blocking/disabling a system app listed by aSpotCat since the stability of the OS can be affected.

As you would have guessed by now, this is a messy solution, relies on trial and error and doesn't guarantee much that you would be able to pin-point the app. However, I don't think there is any way to easily pin-point the app affecting the media volume.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>You may try any permission checker app. The [helpful list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379) maintained by user Izzy on his website may come handy.</sub>
<sup><sup>2</sup></sup> <sub>Input the permission *android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS*.</sub>

Comment: With ADB, one might also consider `adb uninstall -k <package_name>` to make sure the app is gone but not its data (`-k` = "keep data"). So if it turns out an uninstalled app was *not* the culprit, one can re-install its `.apk` using `adb install -r <file>`. Or, if the app didn't opt-out, use `adb backup -apk -f <file.ab> <package_name>`, then uninstall, and `adb restore <file.ab>` if the app was found "not guilty" ;) +1 for the thorough answer!