# How do I find out which App changes the Alarm Volume?

Tags: volume-control

For some reason my alarm volumne sometimes goes to zero. I don't know which app is causing the behavior. Is there an app that can tell me the answer? An app that tells me when my volumne changes and which app is causing volumne changes?

Comment: Related: [Can I know who is changing Android's media volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/137949)

Answer (score 0):

From experience with my  zte zmax2 with Android, it is the built in music player labeled " music player ". Which is a bug needing a patch yet to my knowledge. When on external speakers in the headphones Jack and a song on loop, it has the alarm look all the way up, yet went off at the music volume level despite saying otherwise. Hope this helps.